# Troubles with Bitbucket repositories using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, repository, bitbucket

I have a problem/doubt with the use of repositories and Eclipse

I have a repository stored in Bitbucket, and I want to have it in two computers. 
When I made some changes in one computer, I commit and push it to the Bitbucket repository. 
What can I do to have the repository onto another computer, so I can continue coding in that another computer?

Answer (score 0):

Simply [clone that same Bitbucket repo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Clone+Your+Git+Repo+and+Add+Source+Files) in your other computer.

For that, you can use your same http credential (username/password) or generate another pair of public/private ssh keys.

See "[Bitbucket: Cloning a repository](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Clone+a+repository)".

Also, configure your git username and email with the same values as in your first repo.

Comment: And everytime that I have made some changes at one computer, do I have to clone again the Eclipse repo?

Comment: @a.ras2002 no: only pull. `git pull`, or, from Egit http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Pulling_New_Changes_from_Upstream_Branch

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice. I think that the problem that I have is that I have to configure the same username and email in both computers

Comment: @a.ras2002 yes, using the same git username and email is important.